# Is there SQL function to update table by replacing one column with data (DIFFERENT TYPE) from another column (in a related table)?

Tags: sql-update, inner-join, sqldatatypes, sql-convert

I run into a problem in SQL, I don't know how to update table A by replacing its column "Edu" with another column "Level" of table B.

- Two tables have a relationship in column "Edu"
- **Different data types** bt "Edu" (number) & "Level" (Short Text)
  Can anyone explain why the below code does not work? And kindly suggest a solution. Thanks!

UPDATE
A
SET
A.Edu= CAST(B.Level AS Varchar(Max))
FROM
A INNER JOIN B ON A.Edu=B.Edu;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an idea.
I think your query doesnt work because you try to update a key using a the same time this key, A.Edu.

My solution :
create in the table A a column EduBis with same value as Edu.

Then update with A.EduBis=B.Edu in you clause in the join.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I wonder if any way else to replace values directly on the same column.